# How do i Stop the v.s code source code from displaying all my desktop files?

Tags: visual-studio-code, helper

i just started using v.s code and im still getting around it but im not comfortable seeing "1k plus changes" on the SCM icon.it seems to be tracking all of my files on my desktop and it really makes me uncomfortable.[picture showing SCM tracking changes that do not concern software development](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Olzo.png)

Answer (score 0):

Chances are, you have "opened" your Desktop folder in VS Code.
You can open a different folder via File > Open... or, if you have already a workspace, via File > Open Workspace.

Normally you create a workspace depending on task and then add folders to that workspace. So switching the workspace means switching the project you are working on.

Answer (score 0):

apparently i initialised git in my desktop so all i had to do was to delete the git folder which i couldnt find. so i used terminal to get rid of it .
a) open terminal (b) locate the directories that keep displaying on your code editor (C) log in " rm -rf .git".[deleting the git folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpzG0.png)